# How to calculate days remaining in next Birthday in React using momentJs?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I need to calculate the days remaining in next birthday in React using momentJs library. Can somebody provide me the code?

Comment: Please provide your code example

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Maryam! It's not quite clear what you are asking. Please create a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from the code you have written so far so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: You can use this https://gist.github.com/8bitspixel/01775011cd553f68a6da464f32a7cb7e and then render the results in your React app. But i you mean something else, as the others mentioned, its better if you show some code so we can understand what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = moment([2019, 3, 5]);
var b = moment([2019, 4, 5]);
a.diff(b, 'days') // 30
```

if you want in single line

```
let days=moment([2019, 3, 5]).diff(moment([2019, 4, 5]),'days')
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the right code below:

```
let daysLeft = ( 'Birthday on ' + moment(date).format("D MMM") + ' (in ' +
    moment(moment(date))
    .add(
      moment(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")).diff(moment(date), "years") + 1,
      "years"
    )
    .diff(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"), "days") + ' days)');
```